# How Ole32.lib will get installed?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, visual-studio

I'm using the third party library that uses the Ole32.lib. So linking Ole32.lib will resolves my issue. I found that Ole32.lib was already installed below locations in my PC.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\Win8\um\x64
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.15063.0\um\x64

Here are my queries regarding these paths?

1. How **Microsoft SDKs** and **Windows Kits** paths are created in my PC. Does installing Visual Studio 2017 will generate these paths and Ole32.lib?
2. What is meant by Microsoft SDKs and Windows Kits.
3. What are these different versions(8.0/8.1/10) in Windows Kits.

--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How Microsoft SDKs and Windows Kits paths are created in my PC?

Both those are optional Visual Studio components, of selected while installing or configuring Visual Studio, will result in both/either of those components being installed.  **If they exist on your system you installed them.**

> What is meant by Microsoft SDKs and Windows Kits.
>
> Does installing Visual Studio 2017 will generate these paths and Ole32.lib?

Ole32.dll is installed by installing the Windows SDK not Visual Studio.  You can install the Windows SDK, by selecting that components, when you install Visual Studio.

One is the Windows 8.0 SDK the other is the Windows 10 SDK.  They are both required for software development.

> What are these different versions(8.0/8.1/10) in Windows Kits.

There are only one version for Windows 8, one version for Windows 8.1, but a specific version for each version of windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @Ramhound. This information really helpful for me. 
Does Ole32.lib in the Microsoft SDK and Windows SDK are the same? In my project if i link the Ole32.lib from the any of these two locations has resolved my isse.